# Vercel web hosting issue

Tags: python, html, css, web, vercel

I have just deployed a website in vercel. But when I am running the link it is showing "404: NOT_FOUND". Please help me to solve the issue.
Website link: https://texttoimage-git-main-subhrajyoti-mahatos-projects.vercel.app/

Comment: Please share your github repository if you can, it is hard to guess what might have gone wrong from this.

Comment: Hi @AyushMhetre ! This is my github repository: https://github.com/subhracoder/texttoimage.git